# angularjs client side app without a webserver solutions

Tags: angularjs

I have a small angularjs app, that reads data from a json file and shows it on the screen. I wanted to share this via dropbox to multiple people, so that they double click on the html file and open it on their browser.

Chrome will not allow you to run javascript from the file system and it needs to be started with

```
--allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security --allow-file-access
```

in order for the app to run.

Firefox and Safari both run the app without any issue.

I was wondering, since I am targeting windows systems predominantly, is there a way I can force the index.html file to be opened via firefox if the user has it installed, if not after asking the user's permission download it for him and then open the index.html file? Can I make an 'easy to understand and launch' exe file that does this for the user?

Being a java programmer, I am not sure how to go about doing this..

Comment: Good that you're a Java programmer... the app that does these setup steps can be written using Java, you can make system calls from Java to check if Firefox is available then prompt the user and make the call to get the file from Java.  Browsers are rightfully limited in their access to the file system, you'll have much more control of that part if you just write it in Java.

Comment: You can wrap the app with node-webkit.